# CSV Date Parsing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, parsing

I am trying to parse dates together from the following sample set of data

---

```
No,year,month,day,hour,pm2.5,DEWP,TEMP,PRES,cbwd,Iws,Is,Ir
1,2010,1,1,0,NA,-21,-11,1021,NW,1.79,0,0
2,2010,1,1,1,NA,-21,-12,1020,NW,4.92,0,0
3,2010,1,1,2,NA,-21,-11,1019,NW,6.71,0,0
4,2010,1,1,3,NA,-21,-14,1019,NW,9.84,0,0
```

---

My code is as follows:

```
dateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y %m %d %H")`
dataset = pd.read_csv("raw.csv", parse_dates=['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'], index_col = 0,date_parser=mydateparser)
```

It's throwing this error:

```
ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'day, hour, month, year'
```

Can someone help me understand why I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Try it passing as `dict` or list of list

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv("raw.csv", parse_dates={'date':['year', 'month', 'day',
'hour']}, index_col = 1, date_parser=dateparser)
```

Or

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv("raw.csv", parse_dates=[['year', 'month', 'day',
'hour']], index_col = 1, date_parser=dateparser)
```

PS: Was not able to reproduce the same error, but the proposed solution should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response passing as a list of list works fine but for whatever reason I had to reference the columns by their index number and no the col name.